# Access Instance Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, instance

How do I access the @attrs instance variable from outwith the class? This is an instance of the Twitter class, I need to know how to access the attrs instance hash variable?

```
#<Twitter::User:0x007f5c7c1f71d0 
    @attrs = {
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This question is a little confusing.  Could you give some more context so we can better assist you?

Comment: I'm using the Twitter gem and I'm returning my followers, and I'm looping through each instance of the followers in follower and I'm trying to access the follower background, but when I do 'follower.attrs.entities.profile_image_url_https' it just returns a no method error. So I was wondering how I access the hash inside what appears to be an instance variable named attrs.

Comment: the attrs return a Hash, which does not support this methods youre' calling. try: 
follower.attrs.fetch(:entities, {}).fetch(:profile_image_url_https, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
twittah.instance_variable_get(:@attrs)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this class you have a reader 'attrs' defined at: Twitter::Base, If you follow the inheritance chain of the [Twitter::User](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/user.rb), you will find that the User inherits from Twitter::Base. so you can use the 'twittah.attrs' method